# reshaping a 1x9 dataframe into a 4 x 3 without looping

Tags: r, matlab, dataframe

Basically, I'm sort-of looking for an R version of MATLAB's vec2mat for dataframes. I have a 1 x 9 dataframe (oneBYnine below) I would like to convert into an 3 x 3 dataframe (fourBYthree):

```
> oneBYnine
data
1     4
2     7
3   A.1
4     6
5     5
6     1
7   A.2
8    12
9     6
10    8
11  A.3
12   15

>fourBYthree
a b     c  d
1 4 7 A.1  6
2 5 1 A.2 12
3 6 8 A.3 15

data<-c("4","7","A.1","6", "5","1","A.2","12", "6","8","A.3", "15")
oneBYnine<-data.frame(data)

a<-c("4","5","6")
b<-c("7","1","8")
c<-c("A.1","A.2","A.3")
d<-c("6", "12", "15")

fourBYthree<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

I did this by creating a dummy counter dataframe and then looping (after trying to reshape2 and tidyr until my head exploded).

```
Z<- as.data.frame(matrix(1:12,nrow=4,ncol=3))
Z<-as.data.frame(t(Z))

df<- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=3,ncol=4))
for(i in 1:3) 
  df[i,]<-oneBYnine$data[Z[i,1]:Z[i,4]]

df
```

I can't figure out why some of the data wrangling stuff out there didn't work, and surely there is a cleaner way. Suggestions?

Comment: One doubt.  By converting the `9*1` to `3*4`, do you expect the `a`, `b`, and `d` columns to be `numeric` class?

Comment: Hi akrun - no, I wanted everything as a factor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go via a matrix:

```
# getting your data
oneBYnine = read.table("clipboard", stringsAsFactors = F)

mat = matrix(oneBYnine$data, ncol = 4, byrow = T)
dat = as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = F)

> dat
  V1 V2  V3 V4
1  4  7 A.1  6
2  5  1 A.2 12
3  6  8 A.3 15
```

With `stringsAsFactors = F` each of the columns will be a character. You can convert them to numeric or factor as desired.

Comment: byrow = T.             S$**!**!!$$T - that's exactly what I was looking for, I can't believe I missed it.  Must be the time change.  Thanks.

Comment: Jaap: Done. This was my first Q on StackExchange; still learning my way around.  Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matrix`:

```
fourBYthree<-matrix(oneBYnine,nrow=3,ncol=4,byrow=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t(matrix(data,nrow=4))

  [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
[1,] "4"  "7"  "A.1" "6" 
[2,] "5"  "1"  "A.2" "12"
[3,] "6"  "8"  "A.3" "15"
```